# How to get the object's id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the id on an object, i know the id is hola, but i need to get it during runtime

```
alert($('#hola').id);
```

The idea is this:

```
<script>

    (function ($) {

    $.fn.hello = function(msg) {
        alert('message ' + msg);
        alert('is from ' + this.id); // this.id doesn't work
    };

    })(jQuery);


    $('#hola').hello('yo');

</script>
```

Comment: Inside a jQuery plugin, `this` refers to the jQuery object that represents the selected elements. In this case using `this.attr('id')` as @Joachim posted, is probably the easiest way (and `$('#hola').id` does not work btw).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to read attributes:

```
alert($('#hola').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 9):

The most efficient approach would be:

```
this[0].id
```

`this.attr("id")` takes longer to achieve the same thing because many checks are made and different codepaths are followed based on the parameter passed.  Depending on how often you call the function, there could be a significant difference on, say, a mobile browser with a slow processor.

You can read more about this [here](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element).

Comment: +1 although it has to be checked whether `this` contains elements or not.

Comment: @Felix: yeah, that's good to point out.  `typeof this[0] == "object" && this[0].id` should be sufficient to prevent an error when `this[0]` is undefined or not an object.

Answer (score 5):

You can read it as atttibute:

```
alert($('#hola').attr('id'));
```