# How to retrieve last element id of array in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get id of last element of my array.

This is how I am fetching last element of my array

```
let last = this.Array[this.Array.length-1];
console.log(last);
```

Here is the console of last element of array-

```
Object {id: 48, title: "I'm used to this"}
 title: "I'm used to this"
 id:  48
__proto__:  Object
```

Here is the list on which I have looked already-

[How to retrieve the clicked ElementId in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955930/how-to-retrieve-the-clicked-elementid-in-angularjs)
[How to get the object's id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789902/how-to-get-the-objects-id)
[how to get the id name in html for any object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921699/how-to-get-the-id-name-in-html-for-any-object) and many more but I could not.

I just wanted to access `id : 48`, can any one help me to do so.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What about `console.log(last.id);`?

Comment: It shows this- Error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Seems more a problem with your linter configuration, or use concrete classes and interfaces instead of `Object` if you have such strict linter rules configured.

Comment: Thanks all,
It is working for me, it was issue with declare part, initially it was-
export class classname{ myArray: <object> } which I just changed with export class classname{ myArray: <any> } and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do that:

```
let last:any = this.Array[this.Array.length-1];
console.log(last.id);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do `this.Array.slice(-1)[0].id`, and with `slice` your original array is not changed too.

DEMO :

```js
var array = [{
  id: 43,
  title: "I'm used to this"
},{
  id: 44,
  title: "I'm used to this"
},{
  id: 45,
  title: "I'm used to this"
},{
  id: 46,
  title: "I'm used to this"
},{
  id: 47,
  title: "I'm used to this"
},{
  id: 48,
  title: "I'm used to this"
}]

console.log('last id : ' + this.array.slice(-1)[0].id)
```

**Update**:

As your Array item is type of `Object`, So first convert it to some real `class\interface` type, Something like:

```
export  interface arrayItem{
    id?: number;
    title?: string;
}
```

then define your array type, like :

your Array like

```
this.Array : Array<arrayItem> = [ {
  id: 48,
  title: "I'm used to this"
  },
  //your other array items
]
```

Comment: Nope here is result-  Error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: convert your object into concrete class\interface for your object, like: `export interface arrayItem{id: number; title: string; }`, then make your array of type  `Array<arrayItem>`